# strip content of a table

Tags: javascript, html, xml

I have a static table with lots of data in it. I want to strip out the data with JavaScript and crate an XML result with the result.

table sample:

```
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="50">Sn</td>
    <td width="200">Item</td>
    <td width="500">Discription</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width="200">Item 1</td>
    <td>this is lenghty item discription</td>
  </tr>
```

expected XML result created:

```
<content>
<sn>1</sn>
<item>Item1</item>
<discription>this is lenghty item discription</discription>
</content>
```

...

Can someone please provide me with a simple JS code to use. Thanks

Comment: "Can someone please provide me with a simple JS code to use". No.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    <table width="500" border="0" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0">
    <tr>
    <td width="50">Sn</td>
    <td width="200">Item</td>
    <td width="500">Discription</td></tr>
  <tr>
    <td>1</td>
    <td width="200">Item 1</td>
    <td>this is lenghty item discription</td>
  </tr>
```

Solution...

```
var content = [];
$("table tr").each(function(){
   var self = this;
   content.push({
       'content': {
          'sn': $(self).find('td:first-child').text(),
          'item': $(self).find('td:nth-child(2)').text(),
          'description: $(self).find('td:nth-child(3)').text()
       }
   })
});

var xml = X2JS.json2xml_str(content);
```

The above solution uses the [x2js](https://code.google.com/p/x2js/) library.

```
expected XML result created:

<content>
<sn>1</sn>
<item>Item1</item>
<discription>this is lenghty item discription</discription>
</content>
```